# react Rating component not working as expected

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make the react rating component work but I am getting some strange behaviour. When I make a selection (3 stars for example) the stars don't stay selected.  This is how I want to be able to do it: I have a parent component (handles the state, etc.) that calls a child component. Then the child component makes a call to the React-Rating component. The reason I want to do this is because I want to be able to make these rating components usable in different places; therefore no code duplication would be needed. Below is my code.

```
 //THIS IS FROM MY PARENT COMPONENT.
<Ratings onClick={newRating => this.setState({ rating: newRating })}/>

 //THIS IS MY CHILD COMPONENT THAT CALL THE RATING LIBRARY.
export const Ratings = ({ rating, onClick}) => (

                <div className={styles.rateContainer}>
                  <Rating
                    empty={`fa fa-star-o fa-2x ${styles.rating}`}
                    full={`fa fa-star fa-2x ${styles.rating}`}
                    onClick={onClick}/>// THIS IS TO OVERRIDE THE onClick event on the react library
                  <div>
                    <p className={styles.comments} />
                  </div>
                </div>
);
export default Ratings;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I stored my rating as a part of state and then set the `initialRate` to reflect that state. That made my ratings stick. I think this might be what you are looking for.

```
            <div className={styles.rateContainer}>
              <Rating
                empty={`fa fa-star-o fa-2x ${styles.rating}`}
                full={`fa fa-star fa-2x ${styles.rating}`}
                onClick={ (rating) => this.setState({rating: rating})}
                intialRate={this.state.rating}
            <div>
                <p className={styles.comments} />
              </div>
            </div>
```